# Why are character level models considered less effective than word level models?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, word-embeddings, embeddings

I have read that character level models need more computation power than word embeddings, and this is one of the major reasons for their less effectiveness, but i got curious because the word embeddings need a huge vocabulary while character level models need very less vocabulary, so why is it not considered?

Comment: Effective for what? Can you provide a citation that explains in what task character-level models are less effective?

Comment: @Sycorax says Reinstate Monica effective for language models. I have not found any citations related to it,  but it is widely considered as the above.

Answer (score 1):

Character sequences are much longer than word sequences. This is even more critical with Transformer models that require quadratic memory with respect to the sequence length.

Also, word embeddings are quite efficient in storing information about the words. You need memory to store the information, but the embedding lookup is very fast. With a character-level model, the hidden layers of the model need to be able to build up the same information from the characters. This needs computation time and extra parameters in the hidden layers.

As a result, character-level models are much slower, both because of the longer input sequence and because they need bigger intermediate layers with more parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this was a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are only couple thousands frequently used English words.

> The Second Edition of the 20-volume Oxford English Dictionary contains full entries for 171,476 words in current use.

But for characters with punctuation, upper and lower cases, we can easily get more combinations.